# Copy text to clipboard through safari and read that clipboard data in iOS App

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, clipboard, uipasteboard

Facing problem with the following scenario. Before posting in stack overflow, I spent several hours behind this. Scenario

Step 1: Via Safari (or other any browser) User will browse a page (i.e. www.abcdef.com) and from that page safari will copy text to iOS clipboard (via user on touch event on copy button)

Step 2: iOS Application will be launched and that iOS application will get/read clipboard data (which was saved/written by safari).

Is it possible? and if how? If not possible can you share reason behind that?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can do this,[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Articles/pbReading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008123-SW1) is an example of that

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
if (pasteboard.string != nil) {
    // Do something with the contents...
}
```

Comment: Apple show an error --> nspasteboard -- no known class methdo for selector generalPasteBoard

Comment: Nice Answer. In general paste board, while user copies another data, then my data removes. I need to copy to clipboard with a tag. How to do that?

Comment: Well I don't think you will be able to access this, as *copy* is a default functionality of OS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try to check this

```
UIPasteboard.general.string
```

Comment: Hi @Vlad, I tried through UIPasteboard.general.string  ... It works from one iOS app to another iOS app ... but (A) not working along with web browser like safari ...  (B) probably I can't set data through safari perfectly, can you share any resource / URL for that?

Comment: Mobile Safari does not behave any different from other apps using the pasteboard. As long as the user selects text from a page and copies it, you can paste it anywhere with above code. The only reason why it wouldn't work I can imagine is if the site tries to disable copying all together (with javascript or something). Some sites do that to try and "protect content". Have you tried this with different sites and normal text?

Comment: @rahman are you copying text from safari on the simulator of the safari on mac

Answer (score 0):

I have done the similar thing but for Chrome.
You will need 3 components:

- Browser extention
- Server side handlers
- iOS app

First, you have to create an extension for Safari and put a new option in the context menu probably, or by any other accessible means make it available to the user. Then when the user selects your custom action you send the data to your server.
The server can then push a notification to your iOS app and when the user opens up the app, it can download the newly copied message(s).

Of course, when doing all of these you should think about creating user DB, properly authenticate users and secure the data transmission.